# Text background style

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to resize the text background color to be justified although the text is not.

**http://jsfiddle.net/6kLp9/5/**

**HTML**

```
 <h2>
     <span>content1<br>
           content2 content3<br>
           content4 content5 content6
     </span>
</h2>
```

**CSS**

```
 h2 {
    line-height: 1.5em;
    color: aqua;
    font-size: 1em;
    right: 100%;
    top: 8em;
    width: 40%;
    z-index: 10;
    text-align:left;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    }

 h2 span {
    background-color:black;
    opacity:0.7;}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add following in your css:

```
h2 {
    background-color:black;
}
h2 span {     
    line-height:1.5em;
}
```

Remove

```
text-align:center
```

as you want text left aligned.

Updated [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/6kLp9/27/) here.

Comment: @redditor You cannot have <br> in <span>.

Comment: No i actually want the background color to fill the entire line for example line 3 here... I want the background color of line one to be the same width as line 3

Comment: @user3748039 This fiddle is more what you want. The semantics are a lot better. http://jsfiddle.net/6kLp9/21/ I that the question wasn't particularly well worded so you should mark Hiral's as correct.

Comment: Yes, but when it comes to multiple lines there is no line spacing in between for the background.

Comment: @user3748039 There you go. I've added `margin-top` and `margin-bottom` to your CSS.

Comment: @redditor thanks.. I think I really am not making myself clear.. I'm not sure how to put it in words. I want the text to be left aligned but the background color justified. At the same time I also need line spacing in between.

Comment: @redditor .. That's perfect.. Sorry i couldn't manage to put my request in words properly.

Comment: @redditor: Please do not ask users to do that. They are not obligated to.

Comment: @user3748039 I have updated the answer. I hope finally this is what you are asking for...